# Is there a security measure for Jenkins webhook by Generic Webhook Trigger plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Generic Webhook Trigger plugin with a Bitbucket repo.  The trigger using token is as follows:

```
http://jenkins_url/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=SOME_TOKEN
```

I thought using Token Credential would solve it.  Turned out not to be the case.  It is just like the regular token.  What I don't get is why there is no security measure implemented here.  Anyone with that link can trigger as they will.  Is this something that can't be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

When a specified HTTP POST request is received, the Jenkins Generic Webhook Trigger plugin enables you to start a Jenkins build. The plugin does not by default have any security safeguards for the request's authorization or authentication. This implies that any HTTP POST request made to the specified URL will start a Jenkins build.

You can use one of the following methods to secure your Jenkins webhook:

- Use a secure connection: To send Jenkins the HTTP POST request, use a secure connection (such HTTPS). This will lessen the chance that the request will be intercepted or altered while in transit.
- Authentication can be added; you can set the plugin up to demand it for incoming HTTP POST requests. Setting the "Authentication Token" field in the plugin setup will accomplish this. The authentication token must be included in the HTTP POST request as a header or query parameter in order to use this feature.
- Utilize a webhook secret to increase the security of your Jenkins webhook. In order to use this functionality, you must configure a secret in the plugin's setup and include the secret as a header or query parameter in the HTTP POST request.
- Use a reverse proxy: You can use a reverse proxy to increase the security of your Jenkins webhook by adding authentication, encryption, and rate limitation.

Remember that adding security safeguards to your Jenkins webhook can help prevent misuse and illegal access, but it will also make your setup more difficult. It's crucial to thoroughly assess your system's security requirements and pick the proper safeguards for your Jenkins instance.

Comment: I am not seeing the Authentication Token section in the build trigger for Generic Webhook.  Is it because it doesn't have it?

Comment: You can use Token Macro plugin for it.